# JavaScript function breaking my deep link in jQuery Address crawling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-address

Strange behavior of JavaScript with jQuery Address (plugin).

I have this code:

```
var handler = function(data) {
$('#conteudo').hide().html($('#conteudo', data).html()).fadeIn(500);
$.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
};
```

And it works. Perfectly.

Now I change the code:

```
var handler = function(data) {
$('#conteudo').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#conteudo').html($('#conteudo', data).html()).fadeIn(500);
});
$.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
};
```

Now the fade out effect works, and after fade in (with new content). Beautiful! But this little change in the way of writing the new content (inside of the new function, after fadeOut) broke my sub-links inside my pages.

Here's a live example:

1. Access this URL: http://impulse.im/clean/2/
2. In the top menu, click on 'Contato'.
3. Now look the `href` of link 'Rafa' in the loaded content!
   `http://impulse.im/clean/2?_escaped_fragment_=%2Fcontato%2Frafa`.
   This is not correct: it should read
   `http://impulse.im/clean/2/#!/contato/rafa`
4. Again: http://impulse.im/clean/2/ - Click on 'Contato'. Now RELOAD the page.
5. The link 'Rafa' is now correct.

What this new function (after `fadeOut`) is doing with the code? Why this function is breaking my link?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe, you've modified some another part of your code as well and problem is that another part. BTW looked in Firebug: you're trying to add `form.js` script, but server returns 404.

Comment: In fact, I had forgotten to remove the `form.js` code. But I think the problem is not my changes. Is only the `fadeOut` change.

Comment: I did tests with the original code, I only added the function after `fadeOut`, in `var handler`. The error was exactly the same. The problem is not in my code. I'm even thinking it might be a bug of jQuery Address.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the address plugin before the html stored in data is actually placed on the page. It happens because you call the `$('#conteudo').html($('#conteudo', data).html()).fadeIn(500)` asynchronously as it's called as a callback to the fadeOut method.

Change it this way:

```
var handler = function(data) {
    $('#conteudo').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#conteudo').html($('#conteudo', data).html()).fadeIn(500);
        $.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
    });
};
```

This will call your address plugin after the new content was placed in the page.

Before it worked like this.

handler returns data -> content fades out -> you call the address plugin but the content isn't placed on the page yet -> after 500ms you the callback adding the content is called.

Now it'll be like this.

handler returns data -> content fades out -> after 500ms the content is added and the address plugin is called

Comment: Tom Tu, doesn't work.

I update the code in [website](http://impulse.im/clean/2). Nothing has changed.

This is important: the code `$.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);` is not the call to Address plugin. This call is in the beggining of the javascript code on index.php.

I don't know why the function after fadeOut does not consider the Address plugin.

Comment: Then you have to call it again - or at least you have to try to - so it catches the newly added links that you add dynamically and transform them for you to the desired format. Don't know the plugin but I'm fairly sure that it isn't handling dynamically added content and cause you the trouble.

Comment: :( I'm trying very hard. Without success. I'm reading the [documentation of jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/), trying, testing, but nothing works. It seems very simple, but I don't have much experience with javascript, so I'm having difficulties. But thanks for your help, anyway! :)

Comment: hey, I'll try to give it a look bit later - got some work on head atm :)

Comment: @RafaLibrenz quick note while I'm looking into it - try to work on the brightness/contrast - I couldn't see a single thing with my laptop screen dimmed :) only vague silhouette of the main logo. :)

Comment: @Tom Tu: Yes, I'm doing tests about the brightness/contrast of logo and texts. The problem is in laptops, because dimmed screens and inclination of LCD screen. I want to find a balance between something visible and something that fits in the "visual approach" we want to pass with our website. Thanks for your opinion, I appreciate it.